# Defining columns in numpy array - TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, numpy

I am defining an array which should look like this

```
['word1', 2000, 21]
['word2', 2002, 33]
['word3', 1988, 51]
['word4', 1999, 26]
['word5', 2001, 72]
```

However when I append an a new entry I get a TypeError.

```
import numpy as np

npdtype = [('word', 'S35'), ('year', int), ('wordcount', int)]
np_array = np.empty((0,3), dtype=npdtype)

word = 'word1'
year = '2001'
word_count = '21'

np_array = np.append(np_array, [['word1', int(year), int(word_count)]], axis=0)
```

Traceback

```
 File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4586, in append
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
 TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your code isn't in a state where it can be copied and run to reproduce your error. What is word, year, word_count?

Comment: They are read from a text file but I'll make a change to the code so it will run. Thanks

Comment: A workaround, `tmp = np.array([('w',1,2)], dtype=npdtype)`, then `np.append(np_array, tmp)`. Not sure why cannot use the data directly. Also note the `(` instead of `[` in tmp.

Answer (score 2):

`append` is a way of calling `np.concatenate`.  Look at its code.  Note it has to make sure the 2nd argument is an array. It does that without knowledge of your special `dtype`.  Try that.  It probably produces a string dtype. Then it tries the concatenate.  So you need to make an array with the correct dtype first.

I discourage the use of `append`; it's better to use `concatenate` directly so you have understand all details.

======================

Expanding on your answer:

```
In [75]: npdtype
Out[75]: [('word', 'S35'), ('year', numpy.int16), ('wordcount', numpy.int16)]
In [76]: column = np.array( [b'word1', np.int16(year), np.int16(word_count)], dtype=npdtype)
In [77]: column
Out[77]: 
array([(b'word1', 0, 0), 
       (b'\xd1\x07', 0, 0), 
       (b'\x15', 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('word', 'S35'), ('year', '<i2'), ('wordcount', '<i2')])
```

I don't think this is what you want.

The correct way to provide data for structured array record is with a tuple, or list of tuples (note the extra ()):

```
In [78]: column = np.array( [(b'word1', np.int16(year), np.int16(word_count))], dtype=npdtype)
In [79]: column
Out[79]: 
array([(b'word1', 2001, 21)], 
      dtype=[('word', 'S35'), ('year', '<i2'), ('wordcount', '<i2')])
In [80]: column.shape
Out[80]: (1,)
```

Now I have a 1d, 1 element array with 3 fields.

Without the [], I get a single element 0d array

```
In [81]: column0 = np.array( (b'word1', np.int16(year), np.int16(word_count)), dtype=npdtype)
In [82]: column0.shape
Out[82]: ()
In [83]: column0
Out[83]: 
array((b'word1', 2001, 21), 
      dtype=[('word', 'S35'), ('year', '<i2'), ('wordcount', '<i2')])
```

I can concatenate several of the 1d arrays:

```
In [85]: np.concatenate([column,column,column])
Out[85]: 
array([(b'word1', 2001, 21), 
       (b'word1', 2001, 21), 
       (b'word1', 2001, 21)], 
      dtype=[('word', 'S35'), ('year', '<i2'), ('wordcount', '<i2')])
In [86]: _.shape
Out[86]: (3,)
In [87]: __['year']   # access the 2nd field (not column)
Out[87]: array([2001, 2001, 2001], dtype=int16)
```

Regarding the need for `b`.  You are using Py3 (as I am), and unicode is the default string type.  So if you had used `U35` in `npdtype`, you could have left off the `b` (bytestring flag).

That `(0,3)` shape initial array is probably not what you want.  0 rows, 3 columns, but still has 3 dtype fields.  Look at a `(1,3)` version

```
In [88]: np.empty((1,3),dtype=npdtype)
Out[88]: 
array([[(b'', 0, 0), (b'', 0, 0), (b'', 0, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('word', 'S35'), ('year', '<i2'), ('wordcount', '<i2')])
```

This has blanks and 0 because of what happens to be in the memory.  They could have been random characters/numbers.

`numpy` lets you make arrays with one or more 0 dimensions, but they usually aren't useful.  About the only place they appear is as the starting point for an iterative array definition, e.g.

```
 arr = np.empty((0,3))
 for i in range(10):
     arr = np.append(arr, [i,i+1,i+2])
```

which is better writen as

```
 ll = []
 for i in range(10):
     ll.append([i,i+1,i+2])
 arr = np.array(ll)
```

or

```
 arr = np.empty((10,3))
 for i in range(10):
     arr[i,:]=[i,i+1,i+2]
```

repeated array concatenate is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @hpaulj's advice and then tidy up.

```
import numpy as np

npdtype = [('word', 'S35'), ('year', np.int16), ('wordcount', np.int16)]
np_array = np.empty((0,3), dtype=npdtype)

word = 'word1'
year = '2001'
word_count = '21'

column = np.array( [b'word1', np.int16(year), np.int16(word_count)], dtype=npdtype)
print (column.shape)
column.shape=-1,3
print (column.shape)
print (column)
result=np.concatenate((np_array,column),axis=0)
print (result)

#~ np_array = np.append(np_array, [['word1', int(year), int(word_count)]], axis=0)
```

The two things that I found:

- Meticulous matching of the types of record items is required, hence the use of numpy types in the definition of npdtype and conversions of strings; and also use of **b** prefix to the first element of the record.
- The created column has a curious shape, thus the need to reshape it.

Here's the output.

```
>pythonw -u "temp.py"
(3,)
(1, 3)
[[(b'word1', 0, 0) (b'\xd1\x07', 0, 0) (b'\x15', 0, 0)]]
[[(b'word1', 0, 0) (b'\xd1\x07', 0, 0) (b'\x15', 0, 0)]]
>Exit code: 0
```

Comment: Print the initial `column`; I don't think it is what you expect.  I added illustrations to my answer.

Comment: It put the numbers in the word field, leaving the number fields 0.